# How to delete the oldest file in a folder?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I am writing a batch script to backup files and want to include logic that deletes the oldest file in the folder if the number of backups ever exceeds a certain number set by a variable. Pretty new to batch and my current code deletes all files once it exceeds the number.

Any ideas how to do this?

```
SET Count=0
FOR %%A IN ("%SNAPSHOTNAME%*.*") DO SET /A Count += 1
IF %Count% gtr %NumberOfBackups% FOR %%A IN ("%SNAPSHOTNAME%_PBCS_Test_*.*") DO del "%%A"
```

Answer (score 5):

I suggest the following single command line for this task:

```
for /F "skip=%NumberOfBackups% eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%SNAPSHOTNAME%_PBCS_Test_*.*" /A-D-H /B /O-D 2^>nul') do del "%%I"
```

**FOR** executes in a separate command process started with `cmd.exe /C` in background the command line:

```
dir "%SNAPSHOTNAME%_PBCS_Test_*.*" /A-D-H /B /O-D 2>nul
```

**DIR** outputs to handle **STDOUT** line by line

- just non-hidden files because of `/A-D-H` (not attribute directory or hidden)
- in bare format because of `/B` which means file name only
- ordered by last modification (write) time with newest file first and oldest file last.

An error message output by **DIR** to handle **STDERR** is suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL** with `2>nul`.

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** captures this output and processes it line by line according to the options specified in the double quoted string with ignoring empty lines which do not exist in this output of **DIR**.

The first `%NumberOfBackups%` lines are skipped by **FOR** which means the newest `%NumberOfBackups%` are always kept in current directory.

**FOR** by default ignores also lines starting with a semicolon because of `;` is the default for end of line character. For that reason `eol=|` is used to change end of line character to vertical bar which is not possible in a file or folder name and so it is impossible that a file name output by **DIR** starts with `|`.

**FOR** by default splits a line into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab character as string delimiters and assigns just first space/tab separated string to loop variable `I`. This string splitting behavior can be disabled by specifying an empty list of delimiters with `delims=` at end of the options string to get the entire line (= file name) assigned to the loop variable `I`.

So **DIR** outputs the names all non-hidden files matching pattern `"%SNAPSHOTNAME%_PBCS_Test_*.*"` line by line with newest file first and oldest file last and **FOR** ignores the first/newest `%NumberOfBackups%` files and deletes all other older files.

**FOR** does nothing if **DIR** outputs less or exactly `%NumberOfBackups%` file names.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `for /?`

Note: This is nearly the same answer as written by [Squashman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman), but with full explanation how it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you change to using a FOR /F command with the SKIP option, you can get rid of the IF comparison.

```
set "NumberOfBackups=6"
FOR /F "SKIP=%NumberOfBackups% DELIMS=" %%G IN ('DIR /A-D /B /O-D "%SNAPSHOTNAME%_PBCS_Test_*.*"') DO DEL "%%G"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second for loop has no sort and no break condition so as mentioned by you it will delete all files.

A `dir` command can sort the files so instead of taking the `for` over all files take a `for` over the sorted output of an `dir` command. Option `/OD` will sort for file timestamp.

To let for loop handle the output use `for /f`. The break condition is to only delete the first (in this case the oldest) file and than jump out the for loop.

```
IF %Count% gtr %NumberOfBackups% for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /B /OD "%SNAPSHOTNAME%_PBCS_Test_*.*"') do del "%%f" & goto :gotIt
:gotIt
```